# 301 REdirect not working for subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a directory /mydirectory and all its contents that's giving Errors 404 even with REdirect rules in place, when I try to redirect it to the root of www.anotherdomain.com. I don't have matching files or subdirectories in www.anotherdomain.com, so I just want it to move to the root. Right now what's working is if both www. and non-www versions of /mydirectory Redirect perfectly, but any subdirectory like /mydirectory/anysubdirectory displays a 404 not Found Error. I'm trying to fix that ... I did this in an .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com 
RewriteRule ^mydirectory/$  http://www.anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydirectory/$  http://www.anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```